# SQL Server : error converting data type nvarchar to decimal

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

The following piece of code is opening a JSON message and is inserting the value that corresponds to the '$.disgust' field on the JSON message on the `post_metric_score` table. It works fine in general except when the value is something like that:

```
"disgust": 5.6780936574796215e-05.
```

The error that I get is

> Error converting data type nvarchar to decimal

```
INSERT INTO [Database].[post_metric_score] ([post_id], [metric_id], [score])
    SELECT @post_id, 4, [score]
    FROM OPENJSON(@postJson, '$.sentiment_results.emotions')
         WITH ([score] DECIMAL(12, 8) '$.disgust')
```

I tried to add a convert statement in the SELECT statement but it doesn't work e.g.

```
SELECT @post_id, 6, CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,8), [score]) AS [score]
```

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try retrieving the value as a string and using `try_convert()`:

```
INSERT INTO [Database].[post_metric_score]([post_id], [metric_id], [score])
    SELECT @post_id, 4, try_convert(decimal(12, 8), try_convert(float, [score]))
    FROM OPENJSON(@postJson, '$.sentiment_results.emotions')
        WITH ([score] VARCHAR(255) '$.disgust') ;
```

Or use a float directly:

```
INSERT INTO [Database].[post_metric_score]([post_id], [metric_id], [score])
    SELECT @post_id, 4, try_convert(decimal(12, 8), try_convert(float, [score]))
    FROM OPENJSON(@postJson, '$.sentiment_results.emotions')
        WITH ([score] float '$.disgust') ;
```

Comment: I think you may have to go FLOAT and then decimal ....  try_convert(decimal(12, 8),try_convert(float,'5.6780936574796215e-05'))

Comment: @JohnCappelletti . . . I read the question and the sample data just didn't register.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  and JohnCappelletti thank you both for your help. I am gonna use the float directly . My only comment would be that in that case probably we don't need the try_convert(float, [score]) because it is already a float? I accept the answer nevertheless.